# Printing address of a variable as a string

Tags: c, operating-system, hex, printf

While getting familiarized with the operating systems course I'm taking, I came accross this code and I'm having trouble understanding the second part of the print (%s - &i).

```
unsigned int i = 0x00646c72;
printf("H%x Wo%s", 57616, &i);
```

This yields the output of:

```
He110 World
```

First part is just hex representation of a number, how did the address of `i` end up as `'rld'` though?

Comment: (57616)16 = E110, that explains He110

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The address didn't end up being 'rld'.

It works because %s expects a pointer to char (pointing to a null-terminated string of char). And because &i points to i, which is the bytes 0x72, 0x6C, 0x64, 0x00. Which is the null-terminated string of ascii character codes 'r', 'l', 'd'.